# base on this table, how to get the expected output mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

It is kind of challenge. The expected output, all fruits are from ny or ak state and if the mark good=price 10 and bad= price 20 and OK= price 40. So, apple from ny state, have mark good and bad match the price 10 and 20, and apple don't have mark OK row, so no need to compare that. Banana mark bad = price 20, but OK is not equal price 40, so I will rule out banana. pear match OK = price 40 and state=ny and no rows of good and bad mark. Therefore, my output should be apple and pear. How should I do that?

```html
<?php
/*
fruit  state  price   mark
apple   ny      10    good
apple   ny      20    bad
banana  ny      20    bad
banana  ny      30    OK
pear    ny      40    OK
berry   pa      10    good
*/

/*this is my best query but fail to do what I expected*/
SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE state IN ('ny','ak')  AND mark IN ('good',  'bad', 'OK') AND price IN ( '10','20','40') GROUP BY fruit 
?>
```

Comment: Is the value literally `'NULL'` as a string? Or `NULL` as a value?

Comment: When you say "fail to do what I expect", what is the result you are getting with that query? Can you edit your question to include the current result vs. the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

you should where and or condition

You should use a pair of not in

```
select distinct fruit from  my_table 
where fruit not in (select distinct fruit from my_table 
     where (mark, price) not in (select 'good', 10 from dual 
                            union 
                            select 'bad, 20 from dual
                            union 
                            select 'OK', 40 from dual))
state IN ('ny','ak') ;
```

Comment: Thanks for response, you code is good only except for one problem. On the mark column, (good,bad,OK), if any one value didn't match, I want to rule out fruit. Like, the banana match the price on the bad mark, but did not match the 40 on the OK mark, so remove. Your query will output banana because it match the price 20 on the bad mark.

Answer (score 0):

The list of potential fruit that could be returned, because a row matches the specification:

```
SELECT t.fruit
  FROM `table` t
 WHERE t.state IN ('ny','ak')
   AND ( ( t.mark = 'good' AND t.price = 10 )
      OR ( t.mark = 'bad'  AND t.price = 20 )
      OR ( t.mark = 'OK'   AND t.price = 40 )
       )
 GROUP BY t.fruit
```

A list of fruit that we don't want to return, because there is a row that doesn't satisfy the specification:

```
SELECT t.fruit
  FROM `table` t
 WHERE t.state IN ('ny','ak')
   AND NOT ( t.mark = 'good' AND t.price = 10 )
   AND NOT ( t.mark = 'bad'  AND t.price = 20 )
   AND NOT ( t.mark = 'OK'   AND t.price = 40 )
 GROUP BY t.fruit
```

Note that this will also include rows where the mark column has a value other than good, bad or OK.  If we want to ignore rows with other values of mark, then we'd add...

```
   AND t.mark IN ('good','bad','OK')
```

That gives us two sets. We can combine those with an antijoin operation. As an example of what that looks like, if we had tables `fruit_to_include` and `fruit_to_exclude` ...

```
SELECT i.fruit
  FROM fruit_to_include i
  LEFT
  JOIN fruit_to_exclude e
    ON e.fruit = i.fruit
 WHERE e.fruit IS NULL
 ORDER BY i.fruit
```

We can replace those placeholder table names with inline views, using the queries that give us the fruit to include and fruit to exclude.  The only difference here is replacing the dummy table name with (what MySQL refers to as) *derived table*.

```
SELECT i.fruit
  FROM -- fruit_to_include
       ( SELECT t.fruit
           FROM `table` t
          WHERE t.state IN ('ny','ak')
            AND ( ( t.mark = 'good' AND t.price = 10 )
               OR ( t.mark = 'bad'  AND t.price = 20 )
               OR ( t.mark = 'OK'   AND t.price = 40 )
                )
          GROUP BY t.fruit
       ) i
  LEFT
  JOIN -- fruit_to_exclude
       ( SELECT r.fruit
           FROM `table` r
          WHERE r.state IN ('ny','ak')
            AND r.mark IN ('good','bad','OK')
            AND NOT ( r.mark = 'good' AND r.price = 10 )
            AND NOT ( r.mark = 'bad'  AND r.price = 20 )
            AND NOT ( r.mark = 'OK'   AND r.price = 40 )
          GROUP BY r.fruit
       ) e
    ON e.fruit = i.fruit
 WHERE e.fruit IS NULL
 ORDER BY i.fruit
```